# Registration form with email verification

Tags: php, sql, login, webforms

Can someone point me in the right direction: I need to make a website with a registration form, to create accounts with e-mail verification, to write the forms content in a database table or something and to use it later. I have decent knowledge in html, css, wordpress but next to none in php and back-end.

Basically I know how to design a form but don't know what to do with it other than put "post" or "get" in html. What is the simplest and easiest way to do this, or can you even give me some pointers or where-to-start tips since I'm feeling kind of not able to find it.

Comment: Any PHP tutorial should cover how to access request parameters.

Comment: @5gon12eder are you saying this is basic php and not rocket science quantum programming?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should probably work through a PHP tutorial or book first. After that, you'll either know how to solve the problem or, at least, what to ask about specifically. But no, your task is fairly common and doesn't sound super complicated.

Comment: You can start with typing "Registration form with email verification php" in google. I bet you will get enough example you can simply replicate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Assuming a LAMP stack (ie 'M' being the MySql) I would start with one of these. If you're new to PHP then your choice is to go with code examples like here, or get into a framework but it's probably best if you just start with what you need to do. It's daunting at first, but not that hard once you've tried it.

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html

http://www.codingcage.com/2015/01/user-registration-and-login-script-using-php-mysql.html

Comment: It's okay that you're trying to help but the question is out of the scope of this site and answering it only encourages more of these.

Answer (score -1):

If you know WordPress like you mentioned and don't want to learn PHP, why not fire up a WordPress install and use a plugin like [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)
This plugin does the email verification only in the premium version, I think. In fact Googling "WordPress plugin register users" will come up with loads and the official ones have a useful users' rating on the page.

I use WordPress with Mailchimp account and it works very smoothly with full email integration. In fact there is probably a plugin for most functions that anyone might need.